# Retrieve link From database to start browser in Firebase RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase `RecyclerView` I have a button, which has a `onclicklistener`.
That `onClicklistner` contains intent that opens browser.
So how I can change that link from database? I successfully retrieve image, title,description. And and button also support. Starts browser.
But I only don't know how to retrieve link for that button.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;

    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


        private static final String TAG = "Blank Fragment Startd";

        private View frag1View;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private DatabaseReference myref;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            frag1View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) frag1View.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("holly");
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


            return frag1View;
        }


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                    Blog.class,
                    R.layout.individual_row,
                    BlogViewHolder.class,
                    myref
            ) {
                @Override
                //populateViewHolder metod sets all Element which Our Main Componets Contain.
                protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

                    //it gets tittle frm model class and setting it to the viewHolder, same as below
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                    viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());

                    viewHolder.mbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("link");
                            // Read from the database
                            myref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                                    // whenever data at this location is updated.
                                    String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "please wait.... Brouser is Opening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent btn = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                                    btn.setData(Uri.parse(link));
                                    startActivity(btn);

                                    Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + link);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                                    // Failed to read value
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                                }
                            });


                        }
                    });


                }
            };

            //here Adapter is Setting the recyclerView
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        }


        //this Is the BlogViewHolder
        public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            View mView;

            //dowloding Button reffernce for Setonclicklistrner.
            Button mbtn;
            String link;

            //here Reference to all the Elements it Contain
            TextView textView_title;
            TextView textView_decription;
            ImageView imageView;

            public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {

                super(itemView);

                mView = itemView;
                String link;
                mbtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                textView_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            }

            public void setTitle(String title) {
                textView_title.setText(title);
            }

            public void setDescription(String description) {
                textView_decription.setText(description);
            }

            public void setImage(String image) {
                Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                        .load(image)
                        .into(imageView);
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to set the click listener in your `BlogViewHolder` class not in your `populateViewHolder()` method. Assuming that you have a filed in your model class that contains the link that you want to open, if you want the browser to be opened when the user clicks on the title, then use the following code:

```
textView_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "please wait.... Brouser is Opening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent btn = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        btn.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        startActivity(btn);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + link);
    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164126/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-mamo-retrieve-link-from-database-to-start-browser-i).